# Shift+End key selects text instead of going to the end

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I switched very recently from Win10 to Linux Mint 20.1, because Windows is getting worse over the years in terms of optimization. However, I have been used to using it for a decade now, and some behaviour is strange to me.

I have the very same problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/897008/1174430) old thread, where on my laptop, the <kbd>End</kbd> key is located on the NumPad on the same key as the <kbd>1</kbd>. However, the 2017 thread didn't receive much attention, and the answer is far from being convincing.

I also tried several things from the related threads, and after a whopping 3 hours, I have the feeling I didn't do much...

What I tried so far :

1. In [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/57263) answer, it is suggested that I have a look at the settings for my Keyboard. In the *Miscellaneous compatibility options*, I noticed three things related :

   - Num Lock on: digits, Shift for arrow keys. Num Lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)
   - Shift does not cancel Num Lock, chooses 3rd level instead
   - Shift + Num Lock enables PointerKeys

   I tried every combination of these settings, but it didn't help.
2. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/830061) "lifehack" didn't work. Nothing happened.
3. I tried the [GSettings](https://askubuntu.com/a/897077/1174430) shenanigans, but it didn't make much sense to me as I am still fairly new to Linux...
4. I tried the `gnome-tweak-tool` package, but this didn't change anything whatsoever.
5. Editing the `~/etc/default/keyboard` file to having `XKBOPTIONS="numpad:microsoft"` did nothing, even after the suggested `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

So far, I managed to solve all my problems thanks to the help of this stack exchange, but this one is driving me crazy. Every time I want to go to the end of the line in Eclipse and press <kbd>Return</kbd> to start a new line, I delete the whole end of the line, and it's becoming irritating...

Thank you in advance for the kind answers, and sorry in advance if I am not fitting the community guidelines very well !

---

Here are the specs of my Laptop, in case it is of any help :

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-64-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A515-54G v: V1.21 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: WHL model: Doc_WC v: V1.21 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: 1.21 
  date: 07/03/2020 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 35.7 Wh condition: 35.7/48.9 Wh (73%) 
  model: LGC AC14B8K status: Full 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8265U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: C L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 28800 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX250] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
  driver: nvidia v: 460.32.03 bus ID: 02:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce MX250/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.32.03 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-64-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 
  bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: Lite-On driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 04:00.0 
  IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 80.95 GiB (8.7%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10SPZX-21Z10T0 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci 
  v: 3.0 bus ID: 00:17.0 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.40 GiB used: 80.95 GiB (8.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 68.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 60 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 278 Uptime: 5h 14m Memory: 3.69 GiB used: 2.45 GiB (66.4%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: `This "lifehack" didn't work. Nothing happened.` - what do you mean by `nothing happened`? On *nix, if a command succeeds it usually doesn't print any output.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk By "nothing happened" I mean that indeed, nothing showed up in the terminal, but also it didn't change anything (at lest related to my problem). Even after a reboot, the Shift+End behaviour is still still selecting the text.